# How do I obtain count of rows under the visible rows(non Angular) using protractor?

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have the following HTML:

```html
<tr id="resultsRepeaterGrid">
 <tr id="tableheader"></tr>
  <tr id="Data list1_datarow">
    <div style>row 1</div>
    <tr id = "expanded row"></tr>
  </tr>
  <tr id="Data list2_datarow">
    <div style>row 2</div>
    <tr id = "expanded row"></tr>
  </tr>
  <tr id="Data list3_datarow">
    <div style>row 1</div>
    <tr id = "expanded row"></tr>
  </tr>
</tr>
```

What I would like to do is get the count of all the `<tr>` that are children of the `<tr>` with the id of `'resultsRepeaterGrid'`. You'll find below the `protractor` code:

```js
var searchResCount = element.all(by.id('resultsRepeaterGrid'))
expect(searchResCount.count()).toEqual(3);
```

But I am getting an error of

> Expected 1 to equal 3.

I would like to discard the  and  part because I only intend to count the result rows which is under the datalist_datarow. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a selector based on the dom structure above.

```
var searchResCount = element.all(by.css('#resultsRepeaterGrid > tr:not(.tableheader)'))
expect(searchResCount.count()).toEqual(3);
```

However, it is quite possible that you have a timing issue. You can try something like this:

```
  browser.wait(function() {
    return element(by.css('#Data')).isDisplayed();
  }, 10000);
```

Comment: I did this and now I get Expected 0 to equal 3. I also tried to include browser.wait but it would give me another error.

Comment: there is an issue in the timing then. I will update answer.

Comment: this is what i now did: var searchRes = element(by.id('resultsRepeaterGrid'));
 browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(searchRes), 35000);
 expect(searchRes.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
 var searchResCount = element.all(by.css('#resultsRepeaterGrid > tr:not(.tableheader)'));     
 expect(searchResCount.count()).toBe(3); But I am still getting Expected 0 to equal 3.

Comment: I have exhausted my efforts on this issue i still get the same error :( do you think I need to create a for loop to count all the data rows? using an xpath? I have modified the Dom structure above

Answer (score 0):

Your query has to select the rows, right now you're selecting just the table element so it's count is 1.

change your selector to include the tr elements:

```
element.all(by.css('#resultsRepeaterGrid > tr'))
```